# Why does Firefox say it's already running when there's only one profile in use, no-remote switch not used?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I know that if you start your default Firefox profile with the no-remote switch, you won't be able to click on links in other apps without getting the "Firefox is already running" message. However, I am getting the same message with only the default profile running, without having used the no-remote switch.

I can close every Firefox instance, confirm they're closed in the task manager, make sure the profile.lock files are gone, run Firefox - P "empty" to load a totally blank fresh instance of Firefox, and it still behaves as if I have the no-remote flag set.

Here's my profiles.ini file, for what it's worth:

```
 [General]
 StartWithLastProfile=1

 [Profile0]
 Name=default
 IsRelative=1
 Path=Profiles/6hk0uwvm.default
 Default=1

 [Profile1]
 Name=empty
 IsRelative=1
 Path=Profiles/jtnl8bog.empty
```

There's an about:config pref called `browser.tabs.remote` which is currently set to the default value of false.

The problem started after I set up a shortcut to launch a separate process to open my personal gmail, because having work and personal google apps in the same browser was not working. However, the problem persists when not using the shortcuts and even from a blank fresh empty profile with no command line switches and no other instances running.

Not really sure what else to look at at this point, so any troubleshooting help would be appreciated. This is a Windows 7 machine with all the latest updates & Firefox is the latest stable version.

Comment: check for the process listening port and check whether it is running under system user. Also if some of the firefox handle or thread is not closed proper then issue might occur check for unclosed handles using util to debug it further

Comment: I should clarify that my system is Windows 7. If you have any recommendations for utilities, those would be helpful.